# API Platform - Symfony - security_message translation

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony5

I trying to translate Access Denied message.
Im using Symfony 5.3 and api platform 2.6.3

According to [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#configuring-the-access-control-error-message) I can add my custom message by "security_message", and it work fine.

My question is can I translate it using translations ?

I've tried add key in validators.pl.yaml

```
get:
    security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ROOT")'
    security_message: 'access_denied'
```

```
register:
  email:
    used: Podany email jest już zajęty!

access_denied: "Odmowa dostępu."
```

like it works in Symfony

```
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="register.email.used")
```

But it seems to not work this way.

@EDIT

as [@rugolinifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13955011/rugolinifr) mention [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html#customizing-all-access-denied-responses) you are able to catch exception and set translation to it.

Looks like this

```
public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    if (!$exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
        return;
    }

    // Get exception path in profiler 
    $trace = new AccessDeniedException($this->translator->trans($exception->getMessage(), [], 'validators'), $exception);
    return throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($this->translator->trans($exception->getMessage(), [], 'validators'), $trace);
}
```

Comment: In my opnion, there is no chance to do that using the `security_message` attribute. Take a look at [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html) and implements something using [the translator](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/translation.html).

Comment: Hey, I tried this link be4 but just AccessDeniedHandler option and It didn't work.
Anyhow AccessDeniedListener work for this purpose. I'll edit my Question.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use a subscriber to modify/translate the message and then to throw an exception

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Event\Subscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class AccessDeniedTranslableMessageExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private TranslatorInterface $translator
    ){
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['translateException'],
        ];
    }

    public function translateException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $currentException = $event->getThrowable();
        $currentMessage = $currentException->getMessage();
        $translatedMessage = $this->translator->trans(
            $currentMessage,
            [],
            'security',
        );
        $exceptionClass = get_class($currentException);
        $translatedException = new $exceptionClass($translatedMessage);

        $event->setThrowable($translatedException);
    }
}
```